# Where should I store NSUserDefaults so I can update them?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I understand there are a few questions on where to store userDefaults so they're available to everyone. Currently I have mine in the AppDelegate and it's working. However I now want to update a default setting per a users preference.

However, when the user exits the app and starts it again it simply creates the defaults from scratch again.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    NSUserDefaults *sharedPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [sharedPref setObject:@"Washington, DC" forKey:@"defaultLocation"];
    //  

    return YES;
}
```

Obviously this gets set each time the app opens, rendering the users choice obsolete.

**How can you set a default and then let a user change it without it then being overwritten when the app starts?**

Thanks

Comment: This is what registerDefaults is for. When you register a default, it only writes them if a default with that key doesn't already exist.

Comment: @rdelmar `registerDefaults` does not write anything. When you attempt to get a value from `NSUserDefaults`, if a value for the key has been explicitly set, then that value is returned. If there is no value for the key, then the registered defaults are checked for the key.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for that correction. I've been operating under a misunderstanding of how registerDefaults works. I should have read the documentation a little more closely.

Answer (score 4):

You should use registerDefaults: for that

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 // ...
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{@"defaultLocation" : @"Washington, DC"}];
// ...
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code runs a check for whether or not the app has been launched.  It aims to replace `-registerDefaults:`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"setupApp"])
        {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"setupApp"];
            [defaults setObject:@"Washington, DC" forKey:@"defaultLocation"];

            [defaults synchronize];
        }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: A few minutes after I wrote this I located a viable answer, similar to yours. I now perform a check to see if it's the first time the app has been launched and this is the only time they are set which allows the user to update them. Thanks

Comment: This approach isn't nearly as easy and clean as using `registerDefaults:`. This code adds an extra check that is only useful once and it adds a needless extra value in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: It also trades an entirely in-memory operation (~10us) for one that does synchronous IO (~10-50ms) on launch.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is a singleton available to the entire application. You can call it anytime by:

```
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
```

Users can not interact directly with it, you will have to collect the data and then store it. To set a value:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Some Value" forKey:@"MyKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  // to save
```

The user defaults will persist between application launches.

You have to be careful about setting objects, only property list types can be set in the user defaults.

[Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: You do not need to call `synchronize` after setting a value. The OS will persist the updated values once in a while. The only place you should call `synchronize` is in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` app delegate method.